# How do face recognition systems differentiate between a real face and a photo of a face?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, keras, face-recognition

I'm working on face recognition project with python & OpenCV I detect faces but I have that problem 
I don't know how to get t make the system differentiating between real and fake faces with 2D image
if someone has any ideas, please help me.
thank you.

Comment: First coming to my mind is about using a 3d stereo camera.

Comment: this isn't a programming question, more of a theory question,

Comment: The question is too broad/vague, we can only help you with concrete programming questions, not general machine learning problems. This would be a research project on itself. In any case, on the one hand the problem is ill posed, for example a scan of a photo is, in a sense, "a photo of a photo", but you will most likely not be able to differentiate it from a digital photo. If you have RGB-D data or stereo/multi-perspective images then you can try to work out whether the face is "flat", but in the general case you would have to rely on and try to detect things like glares, frames, etc.

Comment: Thank you  so i need a 3d stéréo caméra

Comment: If you can classify eye status of an image as open or close, you should follow this pattern in the video: open, close, open. This handles liveness detection in webcam captures but it still fails if you show video to a web cam.

Answer (score 3):

There is a really good [article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/03/11/liveness-detection-with-opencv/) (code included) by Adrian from pyimagesearch tackling the same exact problem with liveness detector.
Below is the extract from that article

There are a number of approaches to liveness detection, including:

- **Texture analysis**, including computing Local Binary Patterns (LBPs) over face regions and using an SVM to classify the faces as real or spoofed.
- **Frequency analysis**, such as examining the Fourier domain of the face.
- **Variable focusing analysis**, such as examining the variation of pixel values between two consecutive frames.
- **Heuristic-based algorithms**, including eye movement, lip movement, and blink detection. These set of algorithms attempt to track eye movement and blinks to ensure the user is not holding up a photo of another person (since a photo will not blink or move its lips).
- **Optical Flow algorithms**, namely examining the differences and properties of optical flow generated from 3D objects and 2D planes.
  -**3D face shape**, similar to what is used on Apple’s iPhone face recognition system, enabling the face recognition system to distinguish between real faces and printouts/photos/images of another person.
- **Combinations of the above**, enabling a face recognition system engineer to pick and choose the liveness detections models appropriate for their particular application.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using multiple methods, I'm listing some of them here, you can find a few more by referring to some research papers.

- **Motion Approach:** You can make user blink or move which convinces a way that they are real (Most likely to work on video dataset or sequential images)
- **Feature Approach:** Extract useful features from an Image and use them to make binary classification decisions to say real or not.
- **Frequency Analysis:** Examining the Fourier domain of the face.
- **Optical Flow algorithms:** Namely examining the differences and properties of optical flow generated from 3D objects and 2D planes.
- **Texture Analysis:** You can also do Local Binary Patterns using OpenCV to classify the images fake or not, refer this [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/07/local-binary-patterns-with-python-opencv/) for details on this approach.